# Bold a single letter in a word with 'sg.Text()' in PySimpleGUI

Tags: pysimplegui

On PySimpleGUI, how can I bold only a letter in a word with sg.Text(), like **H**ello?

I can only bold the entire word or with space between "H" and "ello" when I do [sg.Text("H", font=("bold")), sg.Text("ello").]  Thanks.

Comment: Text element not support it, you can do it by two Text elements or one Multiline element.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to Jason Yang (in comments); here is how you can use a Multiline element to bold a particular part of your text:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

# Note that the layout includes a Multiline element with a key to reference it, and it is disabled to keep users from editing the text
layout = [
    [sg.Multiline("", key='-VARIEDTEXT-', disabled=True)]
]

window = sg.Window("Test", layout, finalize=True)

# Use the .print function to add segments of text with specified font types
window["-VARIEDTEXT-"].print("H", font='bold', end='')
window["-VARIEDTEXT-"].print("ello", end='')

# This is just the regular window settings
while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
```

In order for the `.print` function to work, you must set the window to `finalize=True`.
Also, by default, `end='\n'` which will create a new line. This is why you must set `end=''` to keep it all on the same line.

Comment: Nice . You can also "reroute cprint" in your Multiline `reroute_cprint=True` and then call `sg.cprint` instead of looking up multiline every time you want to print. `sg.cprint("H", font='bold', end='')`

Comment: If you want your `Multiline` to look the same as `Text` element would look, you could do something like:  `sg.Multiline(key='-VARIEDTEXT-', disabled=True, reroute_cprint=True, no_scrollbar=True, border_width=0, background_color=sg.theme_background_color(), text_color=sg.theme_text_color())`